# What 3D graph does $x^2+2z^2=1$ give?

Tags: calculus, 3d

[image]

I am missing the 3D graph for the equation $x^2+2z^2=1$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: [Play around with Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3d+plot+x%5E2%2B2z%5E2%3D1) :)

Answer (score 1):

It's an ellipse in the $(x,z)$ plane which intersects $(\pm 1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+2z^2=1$ forms an ellipse in the $x$-$z$ plane. $y$ can be anything you like, so in three dimensions this looks like a cylinder centered around the $y$-axis except with an ellipse instead of a circle (the ellipse has a semi major axis of length $1$ in the $x$-direction and a semi minor axis of length $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in the $z$-direction).

This figure is called an elliptical cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

It is an elliptic cylinder orthogonal to the $xz$ plane.

[image]